# Create record via id with relationship DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm fairly new to `Django Rest Framework` (also Django).

I have a `Budget` and each `Budget` will have its `Series`. Whenever I return the `Budget` I return the relation of `Series`:

**BudgetSerializer**

```
class BudgetSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    series = SeriesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Budget
        fields = ('id',
                  'date',
                  'created_at',
                  'document_number',
                  'total',
                  'document_type',
                  'series', 'hash', 'hash_control')
```

**SeriesSerializer**

```
class SeriesSerializer(ModelSerializer):
  fiscal_entity = FiscalEntitySerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = Series
    fields = ('id',
              'created_at',
              'series_prefix',
              'document_type',
              'starts_in',
              'fiscal_entity')
```

Whenever returning a `Budget` it comes with the `Series` as intended but whenever I try to create a new `Budget` it gives the error `Series field is required`. I guess DRF is expecting a whole new `Series` object to be able to create that new `Series` but I wouldn't like to create a new `Series` but reference an existing one by its `id`.

Something along the lines of:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8081/v1/budget/ \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 5755d65e-a159-45c9-949e-14724ace41d5' \
  -H 'Token: 5D4kFFiXjXeOwM4rrA3xwhL8hYnzK9XXQMo1Fym_suDiTEOdznoYlebaT78F9NUnAE_xobAXuT8leLwZy1acaFZ5yAubqhxbx99xvw4ucHNhd1HMEtLhshO0' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d 'date=2019-02-04&document_number=0202&total=221.23&series=0e4e6251b43849d390bca19c7b722e4d&document_type=PF&created_at=2020-02-04%2023%3A50%3A25&last_document_hash_control=h2kY3j0B%2BO2bF2n5zLzvYLGcpf2OeidqY7GCsG2gusvooqoAJUclCykJz8GqaAqq76rbQYb9ICJRZAd0fXGYYH%2Fi6yox%2FJY0k8YRPGlYLANyqJCMxio80sR%2BZONgH%2FrTk0fykwX4q2%2BuMs7qCOXbksY%2FFB773NJYMWjQz1Jo%2BrI%3D'
```

I have tried several approaches as `series = SeriesSerializer(read_only=True)` in `BudgetSerializer` and other approaches that doesn't seem to work.

Could a more experienced dev explain why DRF is waiting for a new `Series` and why we can't simply reference an existing one by its `id`

Comment: Strange that `read_only` doesn't work. What error do you get when you use `read_only`?

Comment: @Ken4scholars no errors. It just gave me the same error `Series is a required field`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `__init__` to change `series` field. For example:

```
class BudgetSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BudgetSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request = self.context.get('request', None)
        if request and request.method == 'GET':
            self.fields['series'] = SeriesSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Budget
        fields = ('id',
                  'date',
                  'created_at',
                  'document_number',
                  'total',
                  'document_type',
                  'series', 'hash', 'hash_control')
```

Then pass request in the serializer like this:

```
 BudgetSerializer(context={'request':request})
```

Or use [GenericAPIViews](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview) or [GenericViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset) which automatically passes the request object into the serializer.